# CERN ROOT: Write/Read binary object representation into a given memory

Tags: c++, memory, io, buffer, root-framework

How can one write/read binary object representation into a given memory in CERN ROOT?

This is what I want:

1. Allocate memory: `buffer = malloc(buffer_size)`
2. Use CERN ROOT to write binary object representation into `buffer` 
   (object of some custom type `MyType`)
3. Figure out where and how many bytes were written to `buffer`
4. Read back the object from `buffer` in another part of the program

This is some of my thinking:

```cpp
const size_t buffer_size = 100'000'000;
void * buffer = malloc(buffer_size)
MyType x;
TBufferFile b(TBuffer::kWrite, buffer_size, buffer); // Is it correct buffer type to use?
b.StreamObject(&x, "MyType");
```

How do I know into what location of `b.Buffer()` or `buffer` and how many bytes were written? How can one read back the object from the memory?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What is "CERN ROOT"?

Comment: https://root.cern.ch/

Comment: root-forum.cern.ch is the preferred place to post questions regarding CERN's ROOT.